# SELECT value from table because two conditions are not met

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have three tables on my database:

**ts_room**

Fields:

```
id (PK)
capacity    
img 
notes   
building_id 
roomstructure_id    
lecturestyle_id
```

**ts_request**

Fields

```
id (PK)
day_id
period_id
roompref_id (FK > ts_roompref.id)
```

**ts_roompref**

```
id (PK)      
request_id (FK > ts_request.id)      
room_id (FK > ts_room.id)
```

I would like to write a MySQL PDO query that selects rows from **ts_room** provided that after running the rows on **ts_roompref** (checking ts_roompref.room_id against ts_room.id) and finding a match - we would then look up the value in **ts_request** and see whether **day_id** and **period_id** both match 1. It would return the total count.

I hope the above explanation makes sense.

Essentially - requests for rooms are made with this system and **ts_roompref** stores the room preferences made for each request. I am trying to find out whether a particular room is booked on a **day** and **period** (denoted by **day_id** and **period_id** in the **ts_request** table), in this case Monday (1) and period (1).

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: I've been thinking of using this sort of structure `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id)` but when the third table came in I just got baffled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this?

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) totalCOUnt
FROM    ts_room a
        INNER JOIN ts_roompref b
            ON a.id = b.room_ID
        INNER JOIN ts_request c
            ON b.request_ID = c.roompref_ID
WHERE   c.day_ID = 1 AND c.period_ID = 1
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)